# How can I easily find enemy units / cities in Civilization 4?

Tags: civilization-4

I'm closing to wiping out an enemy civilization but cannot find their remaining units and cities. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try trading maps with other civilizations, they may have knowledge of where the other civ is.  If you can somehow trick the civ you are hunting into giving you their world map, that's even better
- If you have air units, you can use their recon mission to quickly reveal large amounts of territory

Otherwise you just need to send your units out searching.  If you see one of his units, its likely that his city is somewhere nearby, so focus your searching in that area.  Keep in mind that to wipe out another civ, you only have to conquer thier cities, so don't worry about hunting down each unit.  You should be able to see how many cities they have left by bringing up the diplomacy screen and looking at the section that lists cities they can trade.  Capitals can't be traded, so it will be one more than what is listed.

Comment: There is an option that you have to kill all units as well, but that is not the default.

Comment: Technically they still survive if they have a settler too.

Comment: Experience says the missing city is probably on an island somewhere remote.